# How to use icons as background image for textblock?

Tags: wpf, image, background, textblock

I need an image overlayed on a textblock text on certain conditions. I choose mahapps iconpacks as it has many icons to choose from. Textblock background needs an imagebrush. So, the question is how to associate imagebrush with iconpacks. Thanks.

Comment: Eg; `<TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Anjum\Pictures\penguins.jpg"/>
            </TextBlock.Background>`

Comment: I don't want to download and access the individual .ico files. I need to intuitively reference <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind=.../>